# Which kind of encryption should be used for a secure login system?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, types

I want to create an application in VB.NET with a secure login system.

The application will have a local SQL Server database.

The question is, what will be the best method to save the login credentials into the database encrypted? Which kind of encryption is best for this job?

Comment: You need an iterated, salted hash.  Use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: I recommend rephrasing the question to make it look less like opinion-based, because that is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Using SQL Server CE lacks security period its just a file anyways not a DBMS. If its local why the encryption, or simply just for kicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't **encrypt** login credentials in order to validate users logging in. Put that out of your mind entirely, because doing so is vastly insecure: it is in fact worse than simple plain-text passwords, because it may look secure to a casual glance, but isn't at all. Rather, you hash them with salts and compare the hashes.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602%28v=CS.70%29.aspx) explains how to hash properly in some detail, with code samples, and similarly CodeProject has a [lengthy explanation of the principles involved](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right).